# Enabling partial template specialization for callable with unknown return type?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm working on a parser combinator library, and I've got a class that defines what a parser is:

```
template <typename P, typename allow=void>
struct parser;
```

That I'm partially specializing to do two things:

1. build a parser from a string literal for convenience
2. otherwise wrap a parsing function (which is a callable)

If I can do that, then I can use `is_convertible<T, parser<T>>` as a predicate for my combinators to disallow their use on anything that's not a "parser".

String is easy:

```
template <>
struct parser<string> {
   ...
};
```

But, in general a parser is just a callable that takes a parse_stream and returns an optional result (I'm in c++11 so I don't actually have std::optional, but we'll pretend).  So, something like this:

```
template <typename Result>
using parser_callable = function<optional<Result>(parse_stream)>;
```

So how can I do a partial template specialization for a callable with an unknown return type?  Note I don't want to convert to a std::function, just that it's a compatible callable "thing".

Edit, here's an example of my ideal capability if we had some sort of Scala-ish subtyping constraints and pattern matching...

```
template <P <: optional<R>(parse_stream)>
struct parser<P> {
     parser(P p) : p_(p) {}

     optional<R> operator(parse_stream stream) { 
         p_(stream);
     } 

private:
     P p_;
};
```

Comment: So you want to have a partial specialization for `parser` with `template <typename Callable>` where the expression `callable(some_parse_stream)` results in an `optional<...>`?

Comment: @Justin Yes effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SFINAE. Combined with a type trait `is_optional`, you can enable the specialization for any callable type which returns an `optional` when passed a `parse_stream`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_optional
    : std::false_type
{};

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<optional<T>>
    : std::true_type
{};

template <typename P, typename = void>
struct parser;

// This assumes that you want the parser to consume the `parse_stream`.
// It checks whether the parser can be called with the type `parse_stream&&`,
// which includes functions that take it by value, by `&&`, and by `const&`.
// If you had a specific one in mind, you can specify it. For example:
// std::declval<parse_stream&>() would pass a mutable reference instead
template <typename Callable>
struct parser<Callable,
        typename std::enable_if<is_optional<
            decltype(std::declval<Callable const&>()(std::declval<parse_stream>()))
        >::value>::type
    >
{};
```

<sup>[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/H3nVkj)</sup>

---

[`std::declval<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is a function which only works in unevaluated contexts, but it produces a value of type `T&&` in such a context. Thus,

```
std::declval<Callable const&>()(std::declval<parse_stream>())
```

is an expression that's the same as having:

```
Callable const& callable = ...;
parse_stream some_parse_stream = ...;
// the following expression:
callable(std::move(some_parse_stream));
```

Since we use this in a context where SFINAE applies, if `callable(std::move(some_parse_stream))` were an invalid expression, the specialization will be dropped from consideration.

Comment: Note that it doesn't assume that the parser takes parse_stream by value, it assumes that the parser is compatible with being called with an rvalue. So taking by rvalue reference, or const reference, are both ok. Basically anything except mutable reference. Good answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, I'm not very familiar with declval, so I don't really understand why it works, but it does, gonna stare at this for a bit, thank you!

Comment: I really can't wait for concepts. It would clean this up a lot: https://godbolt.org/g/Kz4nHT

Comment: @Justin If I modify your code to actually instantiate a parser, it's not finding the specialization: https://godbolt.org/g/VZsX3F

Comment: @SeanMcAllister That's because I required the expression to be valid when the `Callable` is a `const&`. Your `operator()` there is non-const. I default to const unless I know non-const is what I want. If you [make the `operator()` const, it works.](https://godbolt.org/g/wsCrpY) If you [remove the requirement to be const, it works.](https://godbolt.org/g/DJgtDs)

Comment: Ah smart, I'm trying to think if I'd ever need a non-const operator()...